# sweetaler2 target opt - swal still outside the target

Tags: javascript, html, css, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I tried the target opt in sweetalert2, but the toast still appear outside the target

what im doing wrong?

here's the code

```
#trial {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    height:200px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

<div id="trial"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = document.getElementById('trial');
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'I will be placed inside the #swal2-container',
        toast: true,
        target: id,
        position: 'bottom-left'
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Here the result:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `target` attribute, all that happens is that the DOM container `.swal2-container` is appended to the target element, but it has a `position: fixed;` style and you will need to override it as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = document.getElementById('trial');
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'I will be placed inside the #swal2-container',
    toast: true,
    target: id,
    position: 'bottom-left'
  });
});
```

```css
#trial {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.swal2-container{
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>

<div id="trial"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

SweetAlert2 has a [`customClass`](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#customClass) property you can use to add custom classes, this includes to the `container`. So you can just create a dedicated class and add it for your specific toast (or if you use Bootstrap 5 you can even use [`position-absolute`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/position/)).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var id = document.getElementById('trial');
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'I will be placed inside the #swal2-container',
    toast: true,
    target: id,
    position: 'bottom-left',
    customClass: {
      'container': 'trial-swal-container'
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#trial {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.trial-swal-container {
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>

<div id="trial"></div>
```